# AttributeError: 'numpy.dtype' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'

Tags: python, numpy, pyspark

I'm running this sparksubmit job, but I'm getting the AttributeError: `numpy.dtype` object has no attribute `_get_object_id`

```
mycursor.execute(
            "SELECT a, b, c, d, e"
            "FROM {} ".format(mysql_schema))
panda_df = DataFrame(mycursor.fetchall())

myschema = StructType(
    [

        StructField('a', StringType(), True),
        StructField('b', StringType(), True),
        StructField('c', StringType(), True),
        StructField('d', StringType(), True),
        StructField('e', StringType(), True),


    ])

spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(panda_df, schema=myschema)
```

The error occurs on the last line when creating the data frame.

I tried printing the values and these are what I got

```
print(panda_df.to_string())

    a   b  c   d  e
0  38  38  N   2  Y
1  49  49  N   3  Y
2  64  64  N   5  Y
3  26  26  N  11  Y
4  36  36  N  12  Y



print(panda_df.dtypes)
a    object
b    object
c    object
d    object
e    object
dtype: object
```

I'm using pyspark version 3.1.1 and numpy version 1.19.5 and pandas version 1.1.5 on MacOS M1.

The above code has no errors running when it's a standalone script, but when run as part of a spark-submit job, the error appears. Any idea what's the cause of the issue or how to fix the AttributeError?

Edit: Turns out the error was caused by a logger that I didn't include in the code above

Answer (score 1):

The values in your table aren't all strings like you're specifying in the schema. Try converting pandas_df to string before creating the schema.

```
panda_df = panda_df.astype(str)
```